# How to handle OPTIONS method before DELETE?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, rest, nestjs

I'm trying to solve the task of managing photos.

I have a function that deletes some concrete image by id. But my code sends two requests. First OPTIONS (as a result I receive 204), second DELETE (i receive 404).

As a result, at the first request, the operation is executed, and at the second I get an error because the request has already been completed and the image is already deleted by the first request.

As I found out that's because of CORS and that's normal behaviour, but I did not find information about how to work with this OPTIONS request.

This is my route:

```
@UseGuards(AuthGuard('jwt'))
@Delete('/delete/:id')
async deleteImage(@Param('id') imageId: number, @Req() auth) {
    return this.imageService.deleteImage(imageId);
}
```

This is my CORS config

```
const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
app.enableCors({
    origin: ['http://localhost:8080', 'http://localhost:8888'],
    methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'PATCH', 'DELETE', 'PUT'],
    preflightContinue: false,
});
app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe({ transform: true }));
await app.listen(3000);
```

Here are screenshots of the responses
[image]
[image]

Drop me a link please, with information about how to correctly work with the OPTIONS request. Thanks.

I'm using NestJS/ExpressJS. CORS is enabled.

Comment: CORS sends a pre-flight request when executing a cross-origin, 'complex' request. The first request (OPTIONS) should not be deleting anything - you need to configure your server such that it only deletes resources when responding to a DELETE request, not an OPTIONS one. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request

Comment: I use Typescript with NestJS; you should just have to add the method as a decorator: `@Delete() <controller method definition>`. Please add your controller code to your question if this doesn't help.

Comment: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-4.2.1 -- the semantics of options are safe, so its the fault of the implementation, not the client, if the current delete behavior results in a loss of property.

Comment: you should add this decorator: @Delete()